# MediaInfo DLL for files in remote server

Tags: media, encode, mediainfo

MediaInfo DLL is working as expected for local files. Is there any way to get info for files hosted in my storage similar to the way ffmpeg works?

If we give url to ffmpeg as input, it gets the info. Similarly, can we get the MediaInfo DLL for remote urls?

I am using http protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the URL as input

```
mediainfo https://example.com/example.mp4
```

Works (same for the DLL and MediaInfo::Open()).

On e.g. Windows, don't forget to put libcurl.dll (with the right arch), used by MediaInfo for HTTP/FTP/... access, beside MediaInfo.dll. this additional DLL is available on the [MediaInfo Windows download page](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows) in the CLI packages if you want to quickly find it.
Linux and Mac builds are usually compiled to use the system libcurl version.

You can also classically use SAMBA access with "\\example\example.mkv" or map a letter to your URL (you didn't say which protocol you want to use, so we have to guess...)

Jérôme, Developer of MediaInfo

Comment: I would like to use HTTP

Comment: I have added libcurl.dll in the bin folder of my c# project but, not able to get the information for remote http url. Can you help me on this? @Jerome Martinez

Comment: I just tested MediaInfo::Open("(HereYourHttpLink)") with MediaInfo DLL 17.10 and libcurl from MediaInfo CLI 17.10 package, both from official MediaInfo Windows download page, mediainfo.dll and libcurl.dll in \bin\Debug created by a build by VS2017, and it works well when I launch the example code, I think I can not help more.

Comment: @JérômeMartinez its very slow if the url does not have file extension, exemple https://bucket123.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=xxx&Expires=xxx&Signature=xxx
but fast with with just https://bucket123.s3.amazonaws.com/video.mp4
is there something we can do to make it faster ?

Comment: @Halid the 1st URL has an extension but I see what you mean, it is due to an implementation choice which was fine on local disk (using disk cache for opening the file several times, for each format parser when extension is wrong), but does not work well on distant URL (too slow, no cache). Relatively easy to fix but some development needed, if you are really interested in removing this issue you may contact us https://mediaarea.net/Contact for discussing about it.